# Making a custom upgrade ROM

Tags: updates, custom-roms, device-firmware

Is it possible to make a custom ROM to upgrade the current version of android that is installed on your phone?

For example, making a 5.1 ROM to put on an pretty much unsupported phone that only has 4.4.2.

I've seen many posts on how to port ROMs between devices, or making your own custom ROM, but all of the ones I've seen require you to stay on the same version of android.

I'm just wondering if I can take a stock ROM, or a cm 12.1 rom or something and port it onto my device. (Which is a LGD393 in case that helps).

Answer (score -1):

Firstly . It is possible to make a custom ROM to upgrade the current version of android that is installed on your phone

Secondly you can't port roms of other devices to your phone . But  you can take the stock rom of your device and make some modifications to upgrade the version of android.

For custom rom development refer here.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2069130

Comment: your second paragraph is incorrect. That is exactly what porting a rom is from one device to another. To be successful the devices need to be similar. http://en.miui.com/thread-14502-1-1.html  http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2370873

Comment: Well, it should be possible to port any version of android to any phone (with some hardware limitations, of course) since AOSP is written for Nexus phones, and OEMs take that and port it to all of their devices.

So, I guess I answered my own question there.... but I have no idea where to even start learning how to do all of that. The custom ROM guide I'm pretty sure is for porting similar versions of android (4.4 -> 4.4) and has nothing for porting to new versions. (4.4 -> 5.1)